# slow disk with InnoDB page compression

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, compression, mariadb-10.5

I have a write-intensive MariaDB with both NVMe SSD and HDD disks. I recently enabled `page compression` (`innodb_compression_default=ON`). I encountered two problems:

1. The database gets slow after a while. `INSERT`s get noticeably slower after one day. When restarting the machine or MariaDB, it gets backs to normal speed.
2. It takes a long time to shutdown MariaDB (~30 min). During this time, the SSDs have heavy disk activity (as checked by `iostat`). Note that it is not flushing the data into the disk. Before shutting down, the number of dirty pages is zero, and there is absolutely no activity in `show engine innodb status \G`.

I think it might be due to the rearrangement of data on the SSD drives (about 50% full). Some sort of activity like SSD `TRIM`.

How can I diagnose the underlying causes?

This is part of my config, which might be relevant

```
key_buffer_size     = 20M
max_allowed_packet  = 5G
thread_stack        = 256K
thread_cache_size       = 8
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 50G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 128M
innodb_log_file_size = 10G
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_compression_level = 6
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0
innodb_io_capacity=2000
innodb_io_capacity_max=30000
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=0
innodb_doublewrite = 0
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_lru_scan_depth=128
tmp_table_size=2G
max_heap_table_size=512M
innodb_purge_threads=8
innodb_purge_batch_size=600
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=50
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown=OFF
innodb-fast-shutdown=0
innodb-ft-result-cache-limit=4G
innodb_compression_default=ON
```

Comment: Ram size?  Disk size?  Value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Frequent queries?

Comment: @RickJames 128GB RAM< 2TB NVMe SSD, 50GB pool size. Yes, it is constantly working with heavy queries (not repeated queries for web service or something like that). It is for the purpose of data analysis. I frequently write and read into/from tables with tens/hundreds of million rows.

Comment: Would "summary tables" help you?

Comment: @RickJames I had checked performance_schema before, but this should be impertinent (I should find/inspect the disk activity when shutting down). I think the problem is an essential task of MariaDB/InnoDB for organising the data written onto the disk. Maybe the reason I faced it (but not reported on the internet) is that I work with large tables for which a massive set of data should be organised. It's common for me to INSERT 100-200 million rows in a single query. The key is that I had the same SDDs before moving from row to page compression, and never faced such behaviours.

Comment: Aha.  A single query with 100M rows builds a huge undo log.  This is probably what is causing the issue.

Comment: By "Row compression", you mean `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED`?  And "page compression" is MariaDB's new thingie?  Please give us a clue of what type of type of data you have (numeric, text, image, json, etc).  How much compression are you experiencing?

Comment: How much compression were you getting?  What percent of the disk is getting filled up?  If possible, measure it in the middle of the operation -- it is likely to fluctuate as it builds the undo stuff, then it _may_ shrink back.

Comment: @RickJames Good tip! I will write a script to monitor the size of ibd file by `du`.  As a general behaviour, page compression is 2/3 of raw compression (which is about 1/3 of the uncompressed table). However, it massively depends on the column types. For some tables, I get 1/10 of the size of the uncompressed table. Surely, page compression is a must. I can store more tables on SDD. The performance is much better than raw compression. 10 times faster `SELECT COUNT(*)` on huge tables.

Comment: If you are getting 10x on a column, it _may_ be practical to change its Datatype.  What settings are you using for "page" compression?  For "raw" compression?  (I want to be in sync with you on _which_ compression you are talking about.)

Comment: 10x for `COUNT(*)` -- watch out.  It sounds like it was too big to fit in the buffer_pool without compression but was when compressed.  But as the table continues to grow, some day you will lose that 10x.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there may be some techniques to extend the 10x.

Comment: @RickJames I have a different theory, it depends on the row length. When the row is larger than the InnoDB page size, `COUNT(*)` is very slow. The tables are simple key-value: `ID int(11) unsigned, Text mediumtext,`. For multi-column rows with a length shorter than 16K, `COUNT(*)` is pretty fast. For row compression, I use KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1 (if not having varchar). page compression is the default settings. `Zlib, compression level 6.

Comment: What is in the text columns?  If it is normal text, don't expect more than 3:1 compression.  Hence `KEY_BLOCK_SIZE` of less than 8 is probably not useful.

Comment: @RickJames yes, it's normal text. Since their sizes are varying, I get the best compression by KEY_BLOCK_SIZE 1. With page compression, I almost never get a compression better than 3:1.

Comment: @RickJames I confirm that the size of ibd file changes (gradually increases) when shutting down MariaDB after numerous `INSERT`s. Although the number of dirty pages is zero and there is no activity in `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`, it seems data is still written to the disk in the case of page compression.

Comment: Non-unique indexes are updated _after_ the `INSERT` is finished.  Could this explain the I/O?  (cf "Change buffer")

Answer (score 1):

I face a similar issue with MariaDB when using page compression.
My inserts would be fast, but after a few hours, inserts would 'freeze' for many seconds/minutes at a time.

I tried tweaking the `innodb_log_file_size` and set it to a higher value (like
56GB) and it reduced the number of times would happen.
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_log_file_size

You can also try tweaking `innodb_io_capacity` and `innodb_io_capacity_max`
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-page-flushing/

I got these recommendations from AWS RDS support team.